# Removing logic duplication in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a legacy code which does the same work on different classes based on case in a switch statement.

Is it possible to reduce code logic duplication in the switch statement below?

I have 3 classes  Giraffe, Hound and Animal. Both classes Giraffe and Hound extend Animal.

```
public class Animal {
   int sleepDuration   
   int noOfLegs;

public setNoOfLegs(int noOfLegs) {
   this.noOfLegs = noOfLegs;
}
public setSleepDuration(int sleepDuration) {
   this.sleepDuration = sleepDuration
}
public getSleepDuration() {
   return this.sleepDuration;
}
public getNoOfLegs() {
   return this.noOfLegs;
}
}


class Hound extends Animal {
    // some  hound specific variables  and functions here   
}

class Giraffe extends Animal{
   // some  giraffe specific variables and functions here
}


public class Jungle {

public someMethod(String caseString)  {
    Animal animal = JacksonMapper.convertBytesToType(animalbyteContent, Animal.class);

    switch (caseString) {
    case "giraffe":                                    
         Giraffe giraffe = JacksonMapper.convertBytesToType(contentInBytes, Giraffe.class);
         giraffe.setSleepDuration(animal.getSleepDuration);                         
         giraffe.setNoOfLegs(animal.getNoOfLegs);
         break;
    case "hound":   
         Hound hound = JacksonMapper.convertBytesToType(contentInBytes, Hound.class);
         hound.setSleepDuration(animal.getSleepDuration);
         hound.setNoOfLegs(animal.getNoOfLegs);
         break;
  default :
         log.error("Hurray!! You discovered a new animal species");
}
}
```

Comment: And you question is?

Comment: from where are you getting CaseString?

Comment: Its passed to someMethod(String caseString)

Comment: Generics won't help you with this directly.

Comment: @Radiodef: What might help? I don't want to add dependency on springs magic converters.  Is there anything in apache or google guava that can help?

Comment: I have no idea what your actual code does so I can't determine that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you first cast to Animal in the first place but anyway, the easiest refactor I can recommend is extract to method. `setSleepDuration` and `setSleepDuration` are shared so you can create a method that accepts two animals:

```
   Giraffe giraffe = JacksonMapper.convertBytesToType(contentInBytes, Giraffe.class);

setAnimalFields(giraffe, animal);
```

where setAnimalFields is

```
public void setAnimalFields(Animal newAnimal, Animal oldAnimal){
         newAnimal.setSleepDuration(oldAnimal.getSleepDuration);
         newAnimal.setNoOfLegs(oldAnimal.getNoOfLegs);
}
```